# Calculate the following expression

Tags: trigonometry

Calculate the value of $\sin a+\cos a$, knowing that $\sin a\cos a=0.48$  and $a$ belongs to $\left[\pi; \frac{3\pi}{2}\right]$?

What I did is:
$$\sin a \cos a=0.48\ \ |\times 2$$

$$\sin 2a=0.96$$

$a= \dfrac{\arcsin \frac{24}{25}}{2} + \pi n$  or $a=\dfrac{\pi-\arcsin \frac{24}{25}}{2} + \pi n$

Now I don't know how to choose the right angles that belongs to the interval from the condition of the exercise! Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference May help to make your question a bit easier to read

Comment: Use:$$(\sin{a}+\cos{a})^2=(\sin^2{a}+2\sin{a}\cos{a}+\cos^2{a})=1+2(0.48)$$ to find the value of $\sin{a}+\cos{a}$. Also observe that there are two roots, which only one of will fit the criteria of the interval given